# swift3 extension functions not called

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm a high school student working on an app in Xcode 8 using Swift 3. I am trying to create a way to create a table view with collapsible sections. I am trying to create a way to have my code create a view that pushes all of the data into organized sections. Im trying to have my data displayed through using an extension. Even when I have a breakpoint after the extension it never reaches that point.

Edit: The rest of the app is built within the Main.storyboard, however (as you can see), this tableViewController is built entirely within code.
I can create a segue to the WeaponSelectVC however, none of the information and sections are displayed. Breakpoints inside the datasource/delegate methods do not 'break' the program and no information is displayed.

Edit #2: From the storyboard, I segue to this TableViewController (WeaponSelectVC) using the following code after a button is pressed:

```
    let window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: WeaponSelectVC())
```

I can see the table loaded for an instant before the Main.Storyboard ViewController (with the button) gets loaded on top of this.
The Table does not contain any of the information or sections when we see it for an instant (it also isn't loaded when I open this separately).

Below is the code from the WeaponSelect class:

```
struct section {
    var name: String!
    var items: [String]!
    var collapsed: Bool

    init(name: String, items: [String], collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
        self.collapsed = collapsed

    }
}

class WeaponSelectVC: UITableViewController {


    var sections = [section]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Weapons"

    // Initialize the sections array
    // Here we have three sections: Mac, iPad, iPhone
    sections = [
        section(name: "Canadian Weapons", items: ["Colt-browning machine gun M1895/14 (Canadian)","Lee Enfield (Canadian)", "Ross Rifle MK III(Canada)",  "Webley revolver (Canadian)", "Lewis (Canadian)", "Mills bomb (Canadian)"]),
        section(name: "German Weapons", items: ["KAR-98K (German)", "Mauser Gewehr 98 (German)", "Luger (German), Stick grenade (German)"]), ]
//        self.tableView.reloadData()

   self.tableView.dataSource = self
//        self.tableView.delegate = self
//        self.tableView.reloadData()
}

}


extension WeaponSelectVC {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].items.count
    }

    // Cell
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell? ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return sections[indexPath.section].collapsed ? 0 : 44.0
    }

    // Header
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header") as? CollapsibleTableViewHeader ?? CollapsibleTableViewHeader(reuseIdentifier: "header")

        header.titleLabel.text = sections[section].name
        header.arrowLabel.text = ">"
        header.setCollapsed(sections[section].collapsed)

        header.section = section
        header.delegate = self

        return header
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44.0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }

}

    //
    // MARK: - Section Header Delegate
    //
extension WeaponSelectVC: CollapsibleTableViewHeaderDelegate {

    func toggleSection(_ header: CollapsibleTableViewHeader, section: Int) {
        let collapsed = !sections[section].collapsed

        // Toggle collapse
        sections[section].collapsed = collapsed
        header.setCollapsed(collapsed)

        // Adjust the height of the rows inside the section
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 0 ..< sections[section].items.count {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you set `tableView.dataSource`?

Answer (score 0):

From which class is the `WeaponSelectVC` inherited? Your extension should be inheriting from `UITableView` .

Your extension class should look like

`extension UITableView {`